# Best of Both Worlds

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a good way to temporarily display a long list of items.

Say I want to see the available Styles in a workbook.  This code nearly works:

```
Sub StyleLister()
    Dim sy As Style
    For Each sy In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & sy
    Next
    Call DisplayList(msg)
End Sub

Sub DisplayList(s As String)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

I get a very tall, thin MsgBox.  It is not tall enough to display the bottom of the list and it has no scroll bar to get to the bottom of the list, but it has a nice **X** button to dismiss the box.

If i use:

```
Sub DisplayList(s As String)
    Dim AXTbox As Object
    Set AXTbox = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=240, Top:=62.25, Width:=134.25, Height:= _
        171)
    With AXTbox
        .Name = "MyBox"
        .Object.Text = s
        .Object.MultiLine = True
        .Object.ScrollBars = 2
    End With
    AXTbox.Select
End Sub
```

I get a TextBox.  If I click in the TextBox, I can see and use the scroll bar.  But it has no **X** button to allow easy dismissal.

I want the best of both worlds - both a scroll bar and a dismissal button.

Any suggestions??

Comment: As a side noete: Rather than `msg & vbCrLf & sy` use  `msg & (vbCrLf & sy)` to concatenate the long string with two joined  small strings rather than the long string with the small strings twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add to excel an User Form where you can put a text box, the form will have his own close button and all the space you need.

After a quick search I found [this video on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oXcct1mOUw) that explain how to add a form to an Excel speardsheet.